# Input field background color changing

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to keep the background color of the input field as 'green', the problem is that when I click on it to write something, the color changes to default white again, here is my CSS code:

```
  input{
            width: 100%;
            color: $white;      
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $grey-light;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
            padding-top: 0.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            background-color: $green;
        }
```

the HTML React part:

```
<form className="form">
 <input type="text" name="name" className="form__name" placeholder="Name*"/>
        
 <input type="email" name="email" className="form__email" placeholder="Email*"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you perhaps applying another style when the input field is focussed?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use the :focus Property.

So like that:

```
input:focus {
   background: #161616;
}
```

Comment: :active is gonna work just when you click on the input. after that it's gonna be the same. :focus sets the css rule as long as the input is focused

Answer (score 2):

You could use `input:focus` to keep the `background green` while typing. Make sure you do **not** have other css which is overriding this css.

**Demo:**

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey-light;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-color: green;
}

input:focus {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form__name" placeholder="Name*" />

  <input type="email" name="email" class="form__email" placeholder="Email*" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input:focus below input to write your css rules for the focus scenario.